# Good algorithms to find lowest density basis for space in $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$?

Tags: algorithms, coding-theory

I have a basis for 15 dimensional subspace ($15 \times 80$ generator matrix for a code) in $\mathbb{Z}_2^{80}$. I would like to find a basis for the space that has the lowest density possible.  I have a theorem that shows that a lowest density basis must have a fixed number of 1s in each vector (row). I am not aware of any algorithms to specifically solve this problem so I am thinking of the following:

1. Compute all $2^{15}$ linear combinations of the basis I have and keep all those vectors that have the target number of ones.
2. Place these vectors as columns of a (potentially large) matrix and row reduce.
3. If I have 15 pivot columns, the vectors that correspond to them form a basis.

Does this sound like a good approach? Can anyone think of improvements or a better way?

Comment: So basically you have the parity check matrix $H$ of a binary $[80,15]$ code; so $H$ is a $65 \times 80$  binary matrix. It seems that the rest of the information is not that relevant : $H$ defines a vector space over $GF(2)$ and you want to find a basis that has the lowest density. Is this correct? I don't have an answer to this but if you simplify the setting of the problem you increase the chance of getting a response.

Comment: For such a small code the greedy algorithm may give a good enough solution (getting to an optimal basis may be a taller order). In general I very much doubt that a general algorithm with a polynomial complexity exists. Somewhat related problems are known to be NP-hard or some such.